# How to avoid repetitive CASE statements in SQL WHILE loop doing INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to simplify this script so that the CASE statements are not duplicated? It can look acceptable in this shortened example but in reality the CASE statement is much longer as I have cases for "every 2 weeks, "every 4 weeks", "monthly", etc. I am using SQL Server and a WHILE statement for performance reason. Would a CTE or MERGE help?

```
        DECLARE @theStartDate DATE
DECLARE @Interval INT
DECLARE @eventCharges TABLE
(
    [EventDate] [datetime],
    Person_Id int
)

SET @today = GETDATE()
SET @Interval = 0

-- delete event charges from previous user  
DELETE FROM @eventCharges

-- Insert the calculated transactions   
WHILE @Interval < 100
BEGIN
SET @Interval = @Interval + 1
INSERT INTO @eventCharges
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Daily' 
        THEN DATEADD(DAY, @Interval, @theStartDate)
        WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Weekly'
        THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @Interval, @theStartDate)            
    END AS EventDate
    ,pcc.Person_Id
FROM @personChargeCurrent pcc   
WHERE CASE
            WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Daily' 
            THEN DATEADD(DAY, @Interval, @theStartDate)
            WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Weekly'
            THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @Interval, @theStartDate)
        END <= @today
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PersonChargeTransaction pct 
                    WHERE pct.Person_Id = pcc.Person_Id
                    AND pct.PersonCharge_Id = pcc.Id
                    AND pct.TransactionDate = 
                    CASE
                        WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Daily' 
                        THEN DATEADD(DAY, @Interval, @theStartDate)
                        WHEN pcc.Recurrence = 'Weekly'
                        THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @Interval, @theStartDate)
                    END)
ORDER BY StartDate
END
```

Comment: Why not create 2 queries one for daily and another for weekly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a CTE should help. Try changing your INSERT  statement to:

```
WITH cte as 
(SELECT CASE
            WHEN Recurrence = 'Daily' 
            THEN DATEADD(DAY, @Interval, @theStartDate)
            WHEN Recurrence = 'Weekly'
            THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @Interval, @theStartDate)            
        END AS EventDate,
        p.*
 FROM @personChargeCurrent p)
INSERT INTO @eventCharges
SELECT cte.EventDate, cte.Person_Id
FROM cte
WHERE cte.EventDate <= @today AND 
      NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 
       FROM dbo.PersonChargeTransaction pct 
       WHERE pct.Person_Id = cte.Person_Id AND 
             pct.PersonCharge_Id = cte.Id AND 
             pct.TransactionDate = cte.EventDate)
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Comment: I wonder if a CTE is more efficient than a function as suggested by Laurence. Probably so although the function would get compiled.

Comment: @YvesCourbier: With the function, you still have to call the function, with three arguments, three times (ie. `dbo.IntervalEnd(pcc.Recurrence, @Interval, @theStartDate)`); this is still duplication of code. With the cte, you just refer to `EventDate`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap this in a function:

```
Create Function dbo.IntervalEnd(
    @recurrence varchar(10),
    @interval int,
    @startDate date -- or whatever data type you're using for dates
) returns date as
begin
    return case
        when @recurrence = 'Daily' then dateadd(day, @interval, @startDate)
        when @recurrence = 'Weekly' then dateadd(week, @interval, @startDate)
    end
end
```

Then

```
Insert Into @eventCharges
Select
    dbo.IntervalEnd(pcc.Recurrence, @Interval, @theStartDate) as EventDate,
    pcc.Person_Id
From
    @personChargeCurrent pcc   
Where
    dbo.IntervalEnd(pcc.Recurrence, @Interval, @theStartDate) <= @today And
    Not Exists (
        Select
            1
        From
            dbo.PersonChargeTransaction pct 
        Where
            pct.Person_Id = pcc.Person_Id And
            pct.PersonCharge_Id = pcc.Id And
            pct.TransactionDate 
                = dbo.IntervalEnd(pcc.Recurrence, @Interval, @theStartDate)
    )
```

There are overheads for using a function. You'll have to decide if the slightly reduced performance is worth the tradeoff for increased readibility.

Comment: Ha! a function... why didn't I think of that? I think you nailed it and also outlined the trade-off choice. Thanks. I would do +1 but I apparently am not allowed (new to this forum).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table in which to insert the calculated fields and then use that table with a join to insert the data / apply the conditions

Comment: Thanks but isn't that what I am doing? This script will create as many rows as needed in the temp table depending on the StartDate, the Interval, the WHERE statement that has two cases (resulting date is less than today and the row does not exist in the target table PersonChargeTransaction). I then use this temp table in a join to update my target table but I did not include the entire script. This code works great, it's just that, in reality, the CASE statement is huge and is repeated 3 times therefore could be a problem for maintenance.

Comment: My idea was similar to the CTE one, just using a temporary table (a second one) to insert just the EventDate and an ID. Using a CTE is more elegant since you don't have to deal with creating the temporary table and deleting the temporary results every time